# Finding the longest hexadecimal number that meets the specified condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

What is the longest number written in hexadecimal notation as $x_1x_2x_3...x_n$ ($x_i$ is a hexadecimal digit), provided that $x_1x_2...x_k$ when divided by $k$ gives the remainder $k-1$ for all $k \le n$ and the middle digit of the number is **b**.

I tried writing a Python program that iterated through and found numbers that match a given condition. But it is not clear what the program stop condition might be. I understand that this problem should have a simpler solution than going through all possible numbers that match the problem condition.

I don't know where to start solving the problem. Can you give me a hint on which direction to look for a solution?

Comment: What do you mean the "middle digit"?

Comment: For example, in the number fb1, b is in the middle. I'm sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: What if it is even length?

Comment: I think that the author of the problem meant that the answer should contain an odd number of digits. Because otherwise, it is not clear how to understand this part of the task.

Comment: I found **536b430ff7b3ef7f9fd3b9ffab337bbfad176ff7c** which has $41$ hexadecimal digits, but I don't know how to derive this without a program. There is a second $41$-digit solution that doesn't have a central **b**, and these are the longest solutions meeting the divisibility conditions.

Comment: @nickgard Yes, that is correct answer. I am also found it with python program.

Answer (score 2):

So you want $x_1 \equiv 0 \mod 1$, $x_1x_2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$, $x_1x_2x_3 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ etc. Notice that each digit you add to the number will not affect the previous digits - $x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}$ still satisfies the previous conditions, even after you add $x_n$. Therefore, we can start from a 1-digit hexadecimal number and "build up".

<s>Other than that I am not sure if there's any shortcut/approach. [Here's my code](https://tio.run/##bVFdT4MwFH2mv@Iki4HOMYXp1CUz8fPVB@MT4YHZblRY25QSQ4y/fbaMZYn6AA/33PNxT3VnSyVnse50t9sxvkbDC/NeRlo1jVjVnC5IMMKr2OqaY9WKmsWtJkEhm09uGiyR5SRYKwNVQUgcaI7VT5nYCOsBU8gNj5K51wsC64iqmr4r3UW0H0wLrblkUU/oR2KNqGm3kc1EjjGSOcZj2KzmMrIUMYT7khzeRRwd9jClOEVCcYJhfbnE@QIjPCjJhBVKeofDFQdv72u4bY3EgBBS@RN9gl8@ycQlojlhDv8SC1fDn405/SZ@Jo@zdILZta/Ayw5NV9TlelXGcoaiNrxgHfHHS5c@9cETH/yFMX/LxpZDs9qrVn2bLNN9LZri7Axpnjtx7ThvmhWW41PYEnVhNryxkO12xQ3pg1W88yLMiWgjpEUUnifp7OJyfnV9c3f/8Pj0HGZuKZ8gjG9D9w@nH0rI/9ZYv@iK@vdF9qh7FkpGGLwqutv9AA) that solves the problem for every **b**.</s>

The code used is implementing a BFS - it attempts to generate all the cases in ascending order. This is useful if we want to find, let's say, all the cases. However, a better approach here is to use **DFS** - which attempts to generate the largest possible number from a specific configuration. For example, from `F` it can generate `FFEB...`. This is a more efficient approach for this problem, as it attempts to generate the *largest* (longest) number.

I've also implemented a better check condition. Notice that $x_1x_2\cdots x_n = 16(x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}) + x_n \equiv n-1 \mod n$. Now since we know that $0 \leq x_n \leq 15$, we can check if $16(x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}) \equiv n-1-t \mod n$ for some $t$ between 0 and 15.

Code: https://repl.it/repls/YellowFrigidComputer

Comment: I haven't this interpretation for middle digit = $b$. I was interpreting $b$ as the 11th digit in base 16. Can the OP tell us the right interpretation ?

Comment: Why 11th digit?

Comment: I need some time to sort out your answer. Thank you for the explanation and solution code. b is equal 11.

Comment: @skyfroger If you don't understand please ask.

Comment: @Gareth Ma : The digits in base 16 are $0,1,...,9, a,b,c,d,e,f$, isn't it ?

Comment: I see. I've updated my code, it evaluates for all $0,1,2,\cdots, E, F$.

Comment: The bound 38 seems arbitrary - a more natural condition would be "while k is not empty"

Comment: After 38, there're no more configurations. This is tested manually. But yes you're correct.

Comment: @GarethMa I thought so (but didn't even bother to check whether at least on of the solutions in the output has length 37)

Comment: @GarethMa so, from your script I got this number as a solution: F0B53AFA5AFB18FB1C3393F99871D11. It has a hexadecimal B in the middle, but this solution didn't fit. The test system that checks the answers reported that this is an incorrect answer. The number 38 in the range function means that we are looking for the answer with the number of digits $\le 37$?

Comment: Yes. Try replacing it by a while condition loop, though the answer shouldn’t change

Comment: @skyfroger I’m sorry there seems to be another bug on my program. I’m not on my laptop right now, can I fix it later? Thank you.

Comment: @GarethMa Yes, of course. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @skyfroger replace the condition 16**t[...] with 16**... but I think the bounds should be changed

Comment: Ok I realise that after replacing with the correct condition, the number of possible configurations grow quite fast, so more speed up is needed. I'll think of it - you need to reduce the number of configurations.

Comment: @skyfroger Updated(updating) my answer